# How do I print all array elements on the same line?

Tags: c, arrays, assembly

I had to delete all the code. What I' looking is how to sprintf all elements of an array in the same line.

The display has 2 lines, I need to print the array 10,24,32,40,51, .....first line
                         and                       10,51           .....second line

Comment: what to explain about sprintf : it is a way of printing and you are printing the array !

Comment: If you have array pointers then you also access it by indice.

Comment: Paul, yes "%d %d ... %d %d"

Comment: @jjboy have you any trouble using sprintf? As i previously say if you use array pointers then also you can access it by array indice as you used in your previous `sprintf` statement.

Comment: JKB, I'm using a loop: 
                char *out; 
                out = str;
  for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
  {
   *out++ = '0'+X[i];
   
    *out = 0;
         }                              I don't know how to do that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *join(int n, const int array[n], const char *format, const char *sep){
    if(!format)
        format = "%d";
    if(!sep)
        sep = ", ";
    size_t len = strlen(sep)*(n-1)+1;//+1 for EOS
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        len += snprintf(NULL, 0, format, array[i]);
    char *result = malloc(len);
    if(!result)return NULL;
    size_t pos = 0;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        pos += sprintf(result + pos, format, array[i]);
        if(i != n-1)
            pos += sprintf(result + pos, "%s", sep);
    }
    return result;
}

int main (void){
    int array[][5]={{10,24,32,40,51},{10,1,99,77,88}};
    int row_size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    int col_size = sizeof(array[0])/sizeof(int);
    char *join_str;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<row_size;++i){
        char *join_str = join(col_size, array[i], "%2d", ", ");
        printf("%s\n", join_str);
        free(join_str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array has 10 elements

```
#define N 10
int V[N] = {10,34, 34, 11};
```

However, it is *partially explicitly initialised* so that indices 0, 1, 2 and 3 contain 10, 34, 34 and 11 respectively. A partially explicitly initialised array in C will have the remaining elements (4 .. 9 inclusive) implicitly initialised to 0.

You then:

```
sprintf (str, "%d %d ... %d %d", V[0], V[1], V[N-2], V[N-1];
```

This isn't code you are actually running, as it is missing a `)`, and `str` is undefined. However, what this would do is write four values to `str` (not the screen), being values 0, 1, 8 and 9 (i.e. the first 2 and last 2 values), i.e. the characters `0 1 0 0` plus a terminating `NULL`.

As you are using `sprintf()` not `snprintf()` you have no way of checking whether this will overflow `str`.

It's difficult to tell what you are then doing because of the formatting of the question, but it appears you are calling a function `array` that might or might not modify the array and print it out again. However, your assembler function is defined as:

```
__asm void array (int V[], int N, int V) ....
```

which has an array / pointer parameter called `V`, a second parameter called `N` (though the main program `#define`s this to 10 (so that won't work), and a third parameter also called `V` which won't work as that's the name of the first parameter.

You also have a mysterious `X` defined to 10, which is then unused.

It's not particularly clear what you are asking and it would be better if you posted a small working code snippet, but I hope the above is of help.